# How to compare two instances of the same struct in Cadence?

Tags: onflow-cadence

I'd like to compare two instances of the same struct to see if their fields have all the same value. I believe that according to [the docs](https://developers.flow.com/cadence/language/operators#comparison-operators) the equality operator wont't work on structs.

What would be the right approach here? Writing a custom `equals` method for the struct?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your instincts are right, a custom `equals` method would be best. Other languages allow for for custom comparators so you can do things like create your own `==` operator for structs. But that’s not a feature atm in Cadence, so an `equals` methods like you suggested would work in this instance.